# Sanitizing databases

Tags: android, database, security, sanitization

When coding with databases on the web with say php and mysql you have to sanitize the data before you insert it into the database to make sure someone doesn't escape quotes etc. Is this necessary in Android and MySQLite? Does it automatically sanitize? Or is it just unnecessary?

Comment: haha yes, sorry. word scramble upstairs :)

Comment: Heh, I was going to answer "DROP DATABASE <dbname>;" :D

Comment: Please provide examples of bad sanitize and what your expectations are from the auto sanitize.

Comment: for instance if the user enters "quotes" do they need to be escaped? \"quotes\" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Yes, reagrdless of platform, you need to sanitize any inputs that comes from untrusted sources (from the user, another system, another app, etc - anything not hardcoded into your application).

2) Yes, you need to do this in Android when accessing a SQLite database (be that directly or through a Content Provider).

3) Sanitizing your inputs before using them in a SQL command to a database is necessary, but it cannot prevent all forms of SQL Injection. The best strategy to prevent this is to make use of Parameterized Queries, which allow the database to distinguish between what is meant to be data and what is meant to be command, so even if a bad input sneaks in and SQL commands appear in the data, the database knows to treat them as data. In standard Java coding, this involves the use of PreparedStatements. In SQLite/Android, you need to use `compileStatement` to create your queries with placeholders for the data (what is derived from untrusted input) and use `bindString` to set those placeholders.

More about this in the excellent [OWASP SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) writeup.

Comment: Can you please guide on how to sanitize the data ?
As per your answer "_In SQLite/Android, you need to use compileStatement to create your queries with placeholders for the data (what is derived from untrusted input) and use bindString to set those placeholders._"  Is it required when using Content Provider methods delete(), query, update() etc ?

Answer (score 1):

This applies equally well here as it does anywhere else, including the internet.

One thing you have to be really careful about is your input to content providers.  People generally write up content providers, and then use them to allow others to interface with their apps.  Usually under the hood, however, the ContentProvider acts as an interface to a database.  This is one place you definitely need to be careful, especially if you allow your apps content provider to be accessed by other apps on the phone.

And yes, anywhere else where the user might enter data, you also need to be careful.  This includes things like editable text fields, things you download from the internet, basically anything you can't trust.

There is a project that does tainting analysis, TaintDroid, but it only exists as a system form (i.e., it works based on runtime modifications not available on all systems).  However, there are also a few research projects going on right now that aim to track what data flows where, which can help you prevent this problem.  (Scandroid [1] to name one of the few.)

[1] SCanDroid: Automated security certification of Android applications,
www.cs.umd.edu/~avik/papers/scandroidascaa.pdf